Is a problem, that is $L$-complete under non-uniform $AC^0$ reductions, necessarily outside of (non-uniform or uniform) $NC^1$?
I don't have much intuition about non-uniformity so the question may be quite naive.

The question is quite vague; it’s not very clear what kind of an answer you expect. You can consider L-completeness under nonuniform $\let\R\mathrm\R{AC}^0$-reductions, why not? It’s sure better than nothing. Yes, it shows unconditionally that $A$ is not in nonuniform $\R{AC}^0$, or even $\R{AC}^0[p]$ for prime $p$, and conditionally, that $A$ is not in nonuniform $\R{NC^1}$. [I don’t see why you want “logspace-uniform $\R{NC^1}$”, as this is weaker than the usual notion of uniform $\R{NC^1}$ (which is $U_E$-uniform). Anyway, it shows nothing more for uniform $\R{NC^1}$ than for nonuniform.]

Thank you, @EmilJeřábek!
Which condition is needed to say that A is not in non-uniform $NC^1$? Just that $NC^1$ is not equal to $L$?
[I mentioned logspace-uniformness because this is what I read in textbooks, I didn't even know what $U_E$ was :)]

You need L not to be included in nonuniform NC^1 for this to imply a separation. If a textbook suggested to use logspace uniformity for NC^1, toss it out. You cannot get a decent definition of a uniform class by using a uniformity that by itself has a greater computational power than the circuit notion to which you want to apply it. The appropriate notion of uniformity for classes below L (such as AC^0, TC^0, or NC^1) is DLOGTIME uniformity. The only catch is that in order to get the right definition of uniform NC^1, the uniformity needs to describe the extended connection language of the ...

... circuit family rather than the, perhaps more intuitive, direct connection language. The two versions of DLOGTIME uniformity using d.c.l. and e.c.l. are called U_D-uniformity and U_E-uniformity; see Barrington, Immerman, Straubing, On uniformity within NC^1, for details (the notions of dcl, ecl, and U_D and D_E uniformity come originally from Ruzzo, On uniform circuit complexity). Uniform NC^1 can be also defined without using any circuits and uniformities at all as ALOGTIME.

Thank you! It's much clearer now
